# Importing class extension - Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, typeerror, babeljs

I've read so many answers to this question but I keep running into this issue again and again without really being able to figure out why. The fairly vague error is pointing at an import in `action.js`...

```
// actions.js
import { api } from "./api"; <-- this is throwing the babel error
```

-

```
// api.js
import BaseApi from "../baseApi";

export default class Api extends BaseApi {
  constructor() {
    super();
    ...
  }

  ...
}

export const api = new Api();
```

-

```
// baseApi.js
export default class BaseApi {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it is `import api from ./api` ?

Comment: I have read somewhere that using both export and export default within the same file can sometimes cause this error. Maybe try remove the default export in api js and expose the class Api as a normal export.

Comment: @Eladian Yeah I tried that, I also switched them around so the singleton was the default export but still seem to get the same issue

Comment: @HemersonCarlin Afraid not, the syntax is correct

Comment: Next thing I would check is that I am definitely getting what I expect when importing from the modules.

Comment: @Eladian I can't log anything around that import statement, even logs before it don't appear in the console

Comment: @Eladian I just noticed that `BaseApi` is `undefined` after imported it in `api.js` so that looks like the issue. Can't see how it's undefined though, the import/export looks fine to me

Comment: My best guess would be the path to the file you're importing is wrong!

Comment: @Eladian figured it out, circular dependancy issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a circular dependancy/importing issue, all sorted!